# Find the diagonal of a linear operator in scipy

Tags: scipy, operators, diagonal, preconditions

I have a function, A(x), that I have turned into a linear operator using scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator:

```
A_operator = scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator((ny, nx), matvec=A).
```

I have an Ax=b problem where I am using the conjugate gradient method (scipy.sparse.linalg.cg) to solve, however it is diverging and so I think my function, A, may be ill-conditioned.

I need to pre-condition by taking the inverse of the diagonal of A.

How do you easily find the diagonal of a linear operator or function? I can only find functions that calculate the diagonal of a matrix, and my problem is too large to explicitly formulate A as a matrix.

Comment: Is A sparse or dense?

Comment: Technically then `A` is a function, not a matrix (sparse or dense).  Though if there's an underlying sparse matrix, it may have a `.diagonal` method.  But in the abstrcat `LinearOperator` sense, all you have defined is what happens when `A(x)` where `x` is a 1d array.

Comment: About all that the `linearOpertor` wrapper adds is dimension checking. ensureing that `A_operator@x` works for `x` with (nx,) or (nx,nz) shape.

Answer (score 0):

I calculated this by hand to find the diagonal of the function if it were a matrix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).